# c# Dynamically Creating openxml Objects in a Loop

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am creating an openxml Excel workbook with multiple sheets. Each sheet will differ only slightly from the next, but each will contain unique data. The number of sheets created will always be different since it depends on ever-changing factors (it could be 7 sheets or 15, etc). I'm trying to learn an elegant way to create these sheets by iterating through a foreach loop.

I came upon suggestions to do this by creating a dictionary, but considering this involves openxml classes, I do not know how to implement this for my scenario.

Strangely, the following code works perfectly in LibreOffice Calc, but Excel throws errors. I need it to work with Excel.

```
foreach (var ExcelDatum in excelData)
{
   WorksheetPart wspBuildSheets = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
   Worksheet wsBuildSheet = new Worksheet();
   SheetData buildSheetData = new SheetData();
   wsBuildSheet.AppendChild(buildSheetData);
   wspBuildSheets.Worksheet = wsBuildSheet;
   wspBuildSheets.Worksheet.Save();
   Sheet buildSheet = new Sheet();
   buildSheet.Name = "";
   buildSheet.SheetId = 2;
   buildSheet.Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(wspBuildSheets);
   sheets.Append(buildSheet);


   Columns buildColumns = new Columns(
      new Column
      {
         Min = 1,
         Max = 1,
         Width = 100,
         CustomWidth = true
       });
   wsBuildSheet.AppendChild(buildColumns);

   row = new Row();
   row.Append(
       ConstructCell("testing " + ExcelDatum.HddSn, CellValues.String, 0));
   buildSheetData.AppendChild(row);

   SheetViews sheetViews = new SheetViews();
   SheetView sheetView = new SheetView();
   sheetView.ShowGridLines = new BooleanValue(false);
   sheetView.WorkbookViewId = 0;
   sheetViews.Append(sheetView);
   wsBuildSheet.Append(sheetViews);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Dan

[Initial Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WVGz.jpg)

[Then after clicking "Yes"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EkzQ.jpg)

Comment: Add the error information you have detected

Comment: Okay I added screenshots. I'll see if I can get any log files. Thanks!